# To show that Pencil of Quadrics contains $n+1$ distinct Singular Quadrics iff the 2 spanning quadrics are transversal

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Given 2 quadrics $G, Q \in \mathbb{P}_n$, not necessarily smooth, how do I show that the pencil of quadrics spanned by them contains exactly $n+1$ distinct singular quadrics iff $\dim(T_pG\ \cap\ T_pQ)=2$ (i.e. $G$ and $Q$ are transversal), for all $p \in G \cap Q$?

Note: Full disclosure, this question is from the final exam of my Algebraic Geometry course which I was unable to solve.

Comment: The matrix of the quadratic form associated with the pencil of quadrics is given by $A+tB$ ; the degree of equation $\det(A+tB)=0$ (where $A,B$ are $(n+1) \ \times \ (n+1)$ (due to projective coordinates) is "in general" $n+1$. Thus there are $n+1$ real or complex roots, each one giving rise to a degenerate quadric. It remains to show that transversality is equivalent to my "in general"...

Comment: Besides, could you give an example of a non-smooth quadric ?

Comment: If $\det A = 0$, then that would be a singular quadric. Hence not smooth

Comment: All right... not smooth in points of self-intersection.